# Why is quicksum very slow in SCIP python interface

Tags: python, scip

I'm using scip python interface on ubuntu. I am trying to add a constraint using quicksum:

```
m.addCons(quicksum(covfinal[i,j]*weightVars[i]*weightVars[j] \
          for i in I for j in J)<=z)
```

This step takes a long time for some reason. I have `I=range(2500)`, `J=range(2500)`. Is there any way to make this step more effecient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no other way to add constraints than with the `addCons()` method. `quicksum()` dramatically decreases the necessary time compared to Python's builtin `sum()` because only one expression instance is created that is then iteratively updated with the single terms. Otherwise, lots of new expression objects would be created which is very expensive.

The (likely) reason why the command takes some time is because you're trying to add a constraint with 6.25 million coefficients - given that `covfinal` is a dense matrix.

Also, be sure to always use the [latest PySCIPOpt version from GitHub](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt):

Comment: Hi, have a tangential question. How does scip compare with gurobi in terms of efficiency?

Comment: Gurobi has a stronger C foundation especially concerning LP and MIP performance. Modeling-wise there should not be much of a difference - both Python interfaces are using Cython and some similar structures. PySCIPOpt provides much more flexibility, since the interface allows to write entire plug-ins in Python whereas Gurobi has a limited number of callback entry points.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, however, quicksum still runs slow in current PySCIPOpt. As an alternative to quicksum, I suggest creating empty constraints and adding the variable coefficients later. Here an MWE.

```
from scipy import sparse
import random
from pyscipopt import Model, quicksum, Expr
from pyscipopt.scip import Term
import time as t

## construct model:
# max {c'x}
# A * x <= b
#   A: random positive sparse matrix 200 x 300
#   b: random right hand side
#   c: objective vector
#   x: variables

numvars    = 200
numconstr  = 300
A = sparse.rand(numconstr,numvars,density=0.005,format="csr")
b = [random.uniform(1,10) for _ in range(numconstr)]
c = [random.uniform(1,10) for _ in range(numvars)]

## 1. benchmark quicksum approach:
m1 = Model()
m1.setMaximize()
x1 = [m1.addVar(obj=c[i]) for i in range(numvars)] # creating variables
t0 = t.time()
for i in range(numconstr): # generating and adding constraints in a loop
    m1.addCons(quicksum(A[i,j]*x1[j] for j in range(numvars)) <= b[i])
print("1: construction time ",t.time()-t0,"seconds")
m1.optimize()
print("1: Optimum ",m1.getObjVal())

## 2. Add rows and set coefficients
m2 = Model()
m2.setMaximize()
x3 = [m2.addVar(obj=c[i]) for i in range(numvars)] # creating variables
t0 = t.time()
constr = [m2.addCons(Expr() <= b_i) for b_i in b]
for k,a_ineq in zip(constr,A):
    X = [x3[i] for i in a_ineq.indices]
    for x,a in zip(X,a_ineq.data):
        m2.addConsCoeff(k,x,a)
print("2: construction time ",t.time()-t0,"seconds")
m2.freeTransform()
m2.optimize()
print("2: Optimum ",m2.getObjVal())
```

Output:

```
1: construction time  3.013126850128174 seconds
1: Optimum  11581263.217800427
2: construction time  0.019999980926513672 seconds
2: Optimum  11581263.217800427
```

Not 100% sure if this is what you were asking for, as your constraints seem to contain quadratic terms. Hope this helps other people anyway.